# Get the annotation value which is on an interface?

Tags: java, java-7

I am using Java7. I have a custom annotation created and annotated it on an Marker interface.

```
@SomeName(name="ABC")
public interface Bank{

}
```

Below is the class which implements the above interface.

```
public class BankImpl implements Bank{

//some code

}
```

Now i have a method in a separate class which takes above class as an input:

```
public void someMethod(Class class){

  //Here i need to get the custom annotation value
}
```

Above method is called as below:

```
someMethod(BankImpl.class);
```

Now inside someMethod() how can i get the annotation value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the class itself does not have the annotation, therefore you'll get a null value when asking for the annotation. You really need to look into all the hierarchy of the class (i.e. superclass and interfaces):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface SomeName {
    String name();
}

@SomeName(name = "ABC")
interface Bank {

}

class BankImpl implements Bank {
}

public class Test {
    public void someMethod(Class c) {
        Annotation annotation = c.getAnnotation(SomeName.class);

        if (annotation == null) {
            LinkedList<Class> queue = new LinkedList<Class>();
            queue.addLast(c.getSuperclass());

            for (Class cc : c.getInterfaces())
                queue.addLast(cc);

            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                c = queue.removeFirst();
                annotation = c.getAnnotation(SomeName.class);

                if (annotation != null)
                    break;              
            }
        }

        if (annotation == null)
            System.out.println("No such annotation !");
        else
            System.out.println("name is: " + ((SomeName)annotation).name());
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.someMethod(BankImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: eitanfar, Is there any short way ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The problem is that you're looking for annotations, which are specific to the class being annotated, and are not being inherited. This means that you need to check for the value in the Bank.class. If the method received the interface class directly, getting the annotation would not result in a null value, and you wouldn't need the rest of the code. The same goes for annotating the class itself with the SomeName annotation.

Comment: I wanted to suggest you use the @Inherited meta annotation on your annotation, but that only works with classes, not interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
String someMethod(Class<Bank> clazz){
        SomeName sn = clazz.getAnnotation(SomeName.class);
        return sn.name();
    }
```

You only need the Class of the inteface to get everything of the Annotation which is annotated on the interface.

Comment: on the interface you can get the value

Comment: An Annotation which annotated on a interface  belongs to the interface,why do you get it from other place ? The annotation is not annotated on BankImpl.